# ASP.Net C# Google Charts not displaying when running

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I'm working on an ASP.Net C# Google Charts internal reporting site but am having trouble getting the chart to display. Code seems to run fine and allows me to run in debug.

I can get to the ASP page, but there is no chart present.

EDIT: Initial issue was down to misplaced ], how silly of me!

I'm now faced with the following in the Browser Console, can any help?

> A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script,
>   https://www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&v=1&packages=corechart,
>   is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY
>   be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor
>   network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be
>   confirmed in a subsequent console message.See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details

.

Code below;

**ASP Page:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ADMReports.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="ADMReports.ADMReports" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="ADMReports" Namespace="ADMReports" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    </head>
     <body>
        <div id="b_sale" style="width:500px; height:300px;">
            TEST
        </div>
    </body>
        <script>
            // VISUALIZATION API.
            google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
            google.setOnLoadCallback(createPIE);

            function createPIE() {
                // SET CHART OPTIONS.
                var options = {
                    title: 'Total Invoices Per Month',
                    colors: ['#888', 'orange'],
                    is3D: true
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "ADMReports.aspx",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var arrValues = [['Year', 'Month', 'OrdersProcessed']];        // DEFINE AN ARRAY.
                        var iCnt = 0;

                        $.each(data.d, function () {
                            // POPULATE ARRAY WITH THE EXTRACTED DATA.
                            arrValues.push([data.d[iCnt].Year, data.d[iCnt].Month], data.d[iCnt].OrdersProcessed]);
                            iCnt += 1;
                        });


                        var figures = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrValues)


                        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('b_sale'));

                        chart.draw(figures, options);      
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Got an Error');
                    }
                });
            }
         </script>
</html>
```

**Code behind asp page**

I will be amending the SQL query to pull from a Stored Procedure, but kept it simple for testing purposes.

```
public partial class ADMReports : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string Year;
    private string Month;
    private int OrdersProcessed;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public List<ADMReports> Total_Invoices()
    {
        List<ADMReports> Invoices = new List<ADMReports>();

        string sConnString = "Data Source=<servername>;Initial Catalog=<DB>;Integrated Security=True";

        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(sConnString);
        SqlCommand objComm = new SqlCommand("SELECT YEAR(DateTimeScanned) AS Year, MONTH(DateTimeScanned) AS Month, COUNT(OrderNumber) AS OrdersProcessed FROM tabTrace WHERE YEAR(DateTimeScanned) = YEAR(GETDATE()) GROUP BY MONTH(DateTimeScanned), YEAR(DateTimeScanned) ORDER BY MONTH ASC ", myConn);
        myConn.Open();

        SqlDataReader sdr = objComm.ExecuteReader();

        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            ADMReports objValues = new ADMReports();
            objValues.Year = sdr["Year"].ToString();
            objValues.Month = sdr["Month"].ToString();
            objValues.OrdersProcessed = (int)sdr["OrdersProcessed"];

            Invoices.Add(objValues);
        }

        myConn.Close();
        sdr.Close();
        return Invoices;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you can is their error in browser console.... if error provide it here, then its easy to fix

Comment: there is no error message, the google chart simply doesn't display at all.

Comment: Do you have something in the browser's Network tab ?

Comment: Found that there was an erroneous ] in the wrong place, removing resolved the initial issue. It's uncovered a Parser-blocking issue in the browser console - see above

Comment: a couple things __1)__ you're using an old version to load google charts, see --> [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code) __2)__ the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format) for a `PieChart` only allows for two columns of data, third column may only be a string for tooltips...

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to add all related scripts in local project and remove links to third-party references eg. google in this case. This will help in reducing load time for page also you will not be surprised with random updates of such scripts which are hosted on other server.

Comment: You mean to host them on our own server? That's the plan once I've got them displaying correctly. Just need to get them to display with the data from the stored procedure/SQL statement then I'll get the scripts hosted locally

Comment: Yes. In place of referring scripts to third website, include them in your project as local reference. Your plan of doing this once it's working, doesn't seems to solve purpose here.

Comment: Yes that's true, I'll get the saved as local resources. Makes better sense to just do it now.